# Delete specific row in database table

Tags: php, delete-row

Generated html table

[image: Generated html table]

I generate html table with this code.

```
<?php

        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $rows = get_info($db, $username);
        if (count($rows)){
            foreach ($rows as $row) {       
        $_SESSION['row'] = $rows;

            echo "<tr>" .
                "<td>" . $row["den"] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row["chas"] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row["predmet"] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row["profesor"] . "</td>" .               
                "<td>" . $row["prostorija"] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row["tip"] . "</td>" .
                '<td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
                        </span>
                    </button> </td>'
                ;
            }
        }   


    ?>
```

How can i delete specific row (if i click on first "trash", delete first row).

Comment: By posting to the server an identifier for the row you want to delete and then executing a `DELETE` statement in the database.  What have you tried?

Comment: you need to embed the id of the row in your html, otherwise you'll have NO idea which button got clicked.

Comment: Delete by using ajax or query string??

Comment: @Marc B
I have col ID unique for each row but i dont like to show in table.
*Delete by query string.

Comment: @devpro *Delete by query string.

Comment: R u using mysql or mysqli or PDO ?

Comment: @David 
I have no idea how can i reach that row.

Comment: @ValentinGjorgoski: Do you mean that you don't know how to execute a `DELETE` statement on the database?  You might want to start with some introductory tutorials on PHP/MySQL.  Executing database queries is covered by just about any tutorial.

Comment: then how do you expect to be able to detect how/where the user clicked, so you know which record to delete?

Comment: @Marc B if i add ID to html table how can i do that? 
[link](http://imgur.com/lvhme9o)

Comment: per-row, `<form ...><input type="hidden" name="recordID" value="$id"><input type="submit" value="Delete"></form>`, basically

Comment: @Marc B i need query string something like this. 
sorry i'am new in php and pdo.
$sql = $db->prepare("DELETE * FROM `studentraspored` WHERE username = :username and ID =");